# How use Truffle Framework

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-contract, ganache, truffle-test

Anyone please help me to understand what is exactly Truffle & Ganache ?
How to install & use Truffle ?
Please reply who are know this.

Answer (score 2):

truffle suite is framework for developing ethereum based smart contract and integrate it easily with front end. Ganache is tool available in truffle suite, which is used for smart contract development and deployment.Drizzle is another tool of truffle suite to build front-end for smart contract.
you can easily find the installation of truffle suite in internet, it varies based on the os you are using.
https://truffleframework.com/docs
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Truffle**: development and testing suite for smart contracts written in Solidity

**Ganache**: `testrpc` aka your local testnet that Truffle utilizes to test deployments (migrations) of your smart contracts so your testing suite has something to target with near immediate results (no 15s block times!)

Layman terms: your own private, local EVM blockchain

**Drizzle**: Frontend UI

Go here for documentation and tutorials: https://truffleframework.com/docs

[image]